# How to disable OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH for jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I added below as the container env var

```
OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH = true
```

to enable openshift oauth, and each time I access jenkins login, I am redirected to
https://console.paas.intranet.mycompany.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=system:serviceaccount:myproj:sa-edit&redirect_uri=http://myjenkins-mycompany-jenkins-myproj.usi1f.paas.intranet.mycompany.com/securityRealm/finishLogin&response_type=code&scope=user:info%20user:check-access&state=YWNiZmMxMTAtYzU5Ny00

Then, I tried to disable it

```
   OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH = false
```

However, it does not seem to work and I still am redirected to console lnk.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to involve the [`openshift/jenkins-openshift-login-plugin`](https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-openshift-login-plugin) plugin (which means an extreme solution would be to... uninstall that plugin!)

That variable is only useful when Jenkins is runing inside an Openshift pod.

Double-check the [Jenkins initial settings](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/) to understand how to set that variable (for instance, as a java property: `-DOPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH=false`)

In other words, it is important to understand where and when you did `OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH = false`. It needs to be done in such a way Jenkins execution environment inherits that variable.
Hence the proposition to check how Jenkins starts, to make sure it starts with said variable correctly assigned.